# Want Sugest to translate the routes in one language

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im need translate my routes, but need when i call this:

product_path

appear in url produto/x or to all produtos

my problem is because using a gem call 'route_translator' he generate this link product_br_path, i dont want translate my routes in more of one language but some in 1 language, but i dont want use the

```
resources :products,:only => [:show,:index],:as => 'produto'
```

the :as because i want call this path in english, but generate in other language, in my case português, someone have sugestions for me ? I thanks very much.

Comment: solved whit gem rails-translate-routes https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved whit gem rails-translate-routes [github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes](http://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes)

Very usefull and integrate whit i18n of Rails.